# Remove network "GET http" requests warning message from QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I would like to remove the source of this "GET http" request that I am seeing in QGIS that's throwing an HTTP fetch error but I don't know much about the source of these types of requests.

This happens when i open the project. I cant see any WFS layer etc that has any associated request. Is there a solution to remove these messages that has nothng to do with the project i'm working on?

For example, I am seeing the below in the Network Logger
[image]

Then this in my message log
[image]

Is there a way to remove this request completely?

Comment: you can request the cancel option in the code https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsNetworkContentFetcherTask.html  (looks like it's a qgis version checker to see if there are an new versions available?)